# Automate Comparison of Individual rows in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a dataset containing a series of 10 measurements which each have 3 co-ordinates.
I am calculating the 3D cartesian difference between measurements, i.e. measurement  1 vs. measurement 2, measurement 1 vs. measurement 3 etc.

How could I automate the calculation to get every possible output (1 vs 2-10, 2 vs 3-10 etc) ?

Thanks

Comment: try this it may help https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3657-excel-generate-all-permutations.html

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

[image]

Formulas used:

---

- Combinations[ID]: `=ROW()-ROW(Combinations[[#Headers],[ID]])`
- Combinations[H1]: `=SUM(([@ID]=HelpingTable[H1])*1)` as an array formula (confirmed by `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`)
- Combinations[M1]: `=SUM(INDEX([H1],1):[@H1])`
- Combinations[M2]: `=IF([@H1]=1,[@M1]+[@H1],OFFSET([@M2],-1,0)+1)`
- Combinations[X1]: `=INDEX(MeasurementTable[X],MATCH([@M1],MeasurementTable[Meas. No.],0))`
- Combinations[Y1] and Combinations[Z1] just change letter inside `[]`
- Combinations[X2]: `=INDEX(MeasurementTable[X],MATCH([@M2],MeasurementTable[Meas. No.],0))`
- Combinations[Y2] and Combinations[Z2] just change letter inside `[]`
- Combinations[Difference]: `=SQRT(([@X1]-[@X2])^2+([@Y1]-[@Y2])^2+([@Z1]-[@Z2])^2)`

---

- HelpingTable[Meas.]: `=ROW()-ROW(HelpingTable[[#Headers],[Meas.]])`
- HelpingTable[H1]: `=ABS(((MAX([Meas.])-[@[Meas.]]+1)-1)/2*(MAX([Meas.])-[@[Meas.]]+1)-45)+1`

---

The MeasurementTable contains data only - no functions.

Stretch tables as needed.

Rows needed in the Combinations table: `=COMBIN(<Measuremnt count>,2)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I consider a more traditional approach (using the same data as [Lluser](https://superuser.com/users/483121/lluser))

[image]

Build a table with row/column headings (Column F and Row 1). Then in cell G2 use the distance formula (copy/paste to fill the output table):

`=SQRT(SUM((VLOOKUP(G$1,Table1,SEQUENCE(,3,2),FALSE)-VLOOKUP($F2,Table1,SEQUENCE(,3,2),FALSE))^2))`

breakdown:

`SQRT(SUM(( - )^2))` outer portion of distance formula

`VLOOKUP(lookup_value)` determining first or second Meas No based on row/col header

`SEQUENCE()` returns the 2, 3, or 4 (X, Y, Z) column value from the table

Pivoting Lluser's results should result in the same output table as I present